# Hot Reload not working properly with React-Redux and Hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, hot-reload

I'm trying to get hot reloading to work with react `16.9.0` and react-redux `7.1.1`.

This is my code where I want the loading of data (callback in `useEffect()`) called only once:

```
function Sidebar() {
  const dispatch = useCallback(useDispatch(), []);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.info('useEffect');
    dispatch(loadFields());
  }, [dispatch]);

  ...
}
```

Despite using `useCallback()` to memoize the function, when I save a change to another JS file, the callback in `useEffect()` gets called again, reloading the fields.

If I changed the dependency of the `useEffect()` function from `[dispatch]` to just `[]`, however, then it works the way I want and the callback in `useEffect()` does *not* get called on hot reload. But if I do this, the recommended React Eslint complains that I didn't include the `dispatch` dependency.

How do I make the linter happy, while getting hot reloading to work properly with `useDispatch()`?

Other symptoms:

- Using a static `['anything']` also results in hot reloading *not* working; which is strange, because it should be equivalent to `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that I had the wrong idea about hot reloading hooks.

https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/tree/v4.12.15#hook-support

It was precisely that there was any dependency for `useEffect()` that *caused* successful hot reloads, because it is actually rerunning the hooks which makes the hot reload successful, not not running them.

This is to allow you to make changes inside `useEffect()` and have those changes applied by rerunning just your hook without having to refresh the whole page. As long as you are not using `[]` as your hook dependencies. Of course the side effect is that if you *don't* make changes to your `useEffect()` it will *still* rerun it, which is just somewhat inconvenient.

**So basically if I want a hook to not rerun on any code change in the project, I need to make the hook dependencies `[]`.**

But as a trade-off the hook won't rerun even if I make a code change *inside* of it; and of course another trade-off is that it makes the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` eslint rule unhappy.